# Equivalence of RS-integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $\alpha:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a right continuous monotonically increasing function.

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function.

Let's say, $f$ is RS-integrable along $\alpha$ iff the Darboux upper sum and the Darboux upper sum conincide.

(**Information**: Using Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure (w.r.t $\alpha$), it can be shown that $f$ is RS-integrable iff the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero)

Assume $f$ is RS-integrable along $\alpha$. Then, for a given $\epsilon>0$, does there exist $\delta >0$ such that for any partition $P=\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$, $mesh(P)<\delta \Rightarrow  |\int_a^b f d\alpha - \sum_{i=1}^n f(\tau_i) (\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1}))|<\epsilon $ where $\tau_i$ is any value between $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is continuous, then this is trivially true since it is uniformly continuous, but I'm experiencing hard time proving it in the case $\alpha$ is just right-continuous.

Comment: The problem is thus with jumps of $\alpha$. So reduce it to the case of a pure jump, say $a < 0 < b$ and $\alpha(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$, $\alpha(t) = 1$ for $t \geqslant 0$. How could a bad $f$ look like?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. But then what if $\alpha$ has the intermediate value property? (So there is no jump) Would it be true then??

Comment: If $\alpha$ has the intermediate value property and is monotonic, it is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh.. right. Thank you! Could you please look at this post too when you have some time later? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429307/how-do-i-extend-rs-integral-to-bounded-variation-parameters